# Recursive geometric series to explicit formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

I'm trying to figure out how to convert this recursive formula $A_n = \frac{8}{9} A_{n-1} + \frac{6}{5} \left(\frac{20}{9}\right)^n $ into $A_n = 4 \left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^n + 2 \left(\frac{20}{9}\right)^n$ and I'm not sure how to approach it.

The first thing I thought of was to try to find a pattern by substituting a previous term into the next one
\begin{align*}
A_n & = \frac{8}{9} A_{n-1} + \frac{6}{5} \left(\frac{20}{9}\right)^n \\
A_{n+1} & = \frac{8}{9} \left( \frac{8}{9} A_{n-1} + \frac{6}{5} \left(\frac{20}{9}\right)^n\right) + \frac{6}{5} \left(\frac{20}{9}\right)^{n+1} \\
& = \left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^2 A_{n-1}+ \frac{6}{5}\frac{8}{9}\left(\frac{20}{9}\right)^n + \frac{6}{5} \left(\frac{20}{9}\right)^{n+1} \\
& = \left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^2 A_{n-1}+ \frac{6}{5}\left(\frac{20}{9}\right)^n \left(\frac{8}{9}+\frac{20}{9}\right)
\end{align*}
But that didn't seem to work, although it's possible I simplified incorrectly (or not in the way you're supposed to)

--

Actually, I think I forgot a crucial piece of information: $A_0 = 6$

Comment: Use mathematical induction!

Answer (score 1):

$$A_{n+1}=aA_n+bc^n.$$

Try a solution of the form $dc^n$. You have

$$dc^{n+1}=adc^n+bc^n,$$ giving $$d=\frac b{c-a}.$$

Now by subtraction,

$$A_{n+1}-dc^{n+1}=aA_n+bc^n-dc^{n+1}$$

is
$$(A_{n+1}-dc^{n+1})=a(A_n-dc^n),$$

which is easy to solve for

$$A_n-dc^n$$ as it is a geometric progression.

Comment: Thanks! So I was able to get it up to $d=(6/5*20/9)/(20/9-8/9)=2$ but I'm not sure how hat would get me the solution for $A_n$ in the post above since wouldn't the form suggested have $(20/9)^n$ for both the powers?

Comment: @Sat: "both the powers", what do you mean ?

Comment: I need to somehow get it into this format: $A_n = 4 \left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^n + 2 \left(\frac{20}{9}\right)^n$ Right now, I have $dc^n = 2(20/9)^n$ but then what would $A_n$ be? Wouldn't it be $(8/9)(2)(20/9)^n$?

Comment: Did you try to solve my geometric progression ?

Comment: From what I'm doing, $a=8/9$, $c=20/9$, and $b=6/5*20/9$ from the first line and $d=2$ but then aren't all the variables are solved? I get $A_n = dc^n=2*(20/9)^n$. I've never solved a geometric progression with two parts, but when I'm trying to solve the last line, everything seems to cancel out

Comment: @Sat: can you solve $B_{n+1}=aB_n$ ?

Comment: As of now, I'd say no since I'm not sure what it means to solve a geometric progression when it's written like that. I understand that $a$ is the common ratio and it's what one multiplies all the previous terms by.

Comment: $Yves, I've figured it out (I didn't realize I needed the $A_0$ term but once that was discovered then it became good) thanks for your help